# Error: AttributeError: 'powerOfTwo' object has no attribute 'x'

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a python program to check if the positive integer divisable by 2 and return false or true with using classes and functions. I'm getting this error: AttributeError: 'powerOfTwo' object has no attribute 'x'. Can you help me with fixing this?

```
class powerOfTwo():

    def __init__(self, x):

        self.x = x

    def user(self):

        x = int(input("Enter a number: "))

    def check(self):

        if self.x == 1:

            return False

        elif (x > 0) and (x % 2 == 0):

            return True

        else:

            return False

a = powerOfTwo(5)

powerOfTwo().user()

powerOfTwo().check()
```

Comment: `elif (x > 0) and (x % 2 == 0):` -> `self.x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic of checking power of two is not correct.

Try to think about what will be the output for value `6`?

Also your code returns `False` for value `1`, but `1` is a power of `2`.

---

You can do something like this:

```
class powerOfTwo():
    def __init__(self, x = 1):    # Provide a defaul value otherwise powerOfTwo().user() and powerOfTwo().check() will not work.
        self.x = x

    def user(self):               # Use self.x instead of x
        self.x = int(input("Enter a number: "))    

    def check(self):              # Use self.x instead of x
        if self.x == 0: 
            return False

        while self.x != 1:        # Updated the logic.
            if self.x % 2 != 0: 
                return False

            self.x = self.x // 2    

        return True
```